# How to access DOM elements when the ids were dynamically created with numbers

Tags: dom, dynamic

I am building a forum page that submits a number of `comments` with respect to a `subject` much like the one we are on. Hence, when I acess the database to display the comments, I need to dynamically create the id of some `div`'s of my content, something like this:

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
 ?>
  <div id="post<?=$row["postId"] ?>" class="seeForumPost"><?=$row["post"] ?> </div>  //this one 
   <div id="postFooter<?=$row["postId"] ?>" class="seeForumPostFooter"> //this one
     <div class="byUser">  
       by <a class="commonLink" href="<?php print "seeUser.php?userId=".$row['userId'] ?>"> <strong><?=ucwords($row["firstname"]) ?> <?=ucwords($row["lastname"]) ?></strong></a>
 </div>
     <div class="likeThisForum"> Like this Post</div> 
     <div class="numberOfLikes"> (<?=$row["postLikes"] ?> likes) </div>
     <div id="<?=$row["postId"] ?>" onclick="reportPostSpam()" class="markAsSpam">Mark as spam</div>   //this one
  </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Thats right. I am using numbers inside my id, so they appears like `"post26"` `"postFooter26"` and `"26"`
But I don't know how to fetch these DOM objects in my ajax request (prototype). I cant't seem to deal with those `parentNode` and `previousSiblings` properties because then the javascript method throws `cannot call property style of undefined`. Helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try:

```
<div id="<?=$row["postId"] ?>" onclick="reportPostSpam(<?=$row["postId"] ?>)" class="markAsSpam">Mark as spam</div>
```

Would be much simplier

Comment: thanks. So what would I specify in my function  parameter field. say  `function reportPostSpam(//the parameter)`

Comment: its giving me an error here ` var postContentId="post_"+id;
 $(postContentId).style.color="rgb:(255,99,71)"; //cannot read property "style" of null`

Comment: According to your question instead of `var postContentId="post_"+id;` you should write `var postContentId="post"+id;`

Comment: thanks. I didn't try the method on your comment, however I followed your answer and put all my function into `onSucess:function(ajax)`